# Build APK from bare workflow Expo project with native local (offline) module

Tags: build, expo, apk

When building the project with EAS an error is showed:

> no such file or directory, open ‘/absolute/path/to/mypackage-0.1.0.tgz’

Should I use Turtle?
Am I missing something?

Command used to build:

```
eas build -p android --profile=development --local
```

eas.json

```
 {
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.48.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug",
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76987065/5042856

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of combinations:

1. do not use Windows
2. use Unix with Android Studio

   $ cd android && chmod +x ./gradlew
   $ ./gradlew assembleRelease

Also, check this out:

https://instamobile.io/android-development/generate-react-native-release-build-android/

EDIT cause people dislike this answer:

The fact is that **after you eject the project**, you can manage your app as if it is a native app.
If you want to build with a custom package, not published, in local this seems to be the fastest and reliable way.

Comment: Please refrain from discouraging windows, even the link you posted is not suggesting to not use windows. Developers should be able to use any OS of their choice. Also, windows for most part works just fine, even if you need a unix env, with WSL you get just that.