# how to use expo eas build offline --no Internet required

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

Is there any way I can use expo eas build fully offline without requiring an Internet connection.

Maybe an offline package or ...

Comment: Hi, did you find any answers?

Answer (score 10):

You can just run eas build with --local param like
`eas build --platform android --local` or `eas build --platform ios --local` (note, `--platform all` is not allowed in this case).

Its in the documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/local-builds/ (altought I found this question first)

Comment: This still requires on-line capability to determine if the project "exists"

Comment: This answer does not address the need for an internet connection problem.

Answer (score 5):

For others that end up here:

First you need to generate the native app files by executing expo prebuild:

```
npx expo prebuild
```

To directly run the build have a device connected or an emulator running:

```
npx react-native run-android --mode="release"
```

Build with:

```
npx react-native build-android --mode=release
```

For signing the apk for release, follow the instructions on react natives website:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android